# Print a table to new window in R

Tags: r, function, window

In R, plot() opens a new window within R and displays a graph.

Is there a way to do the same thing with a table - without printing to the command line?

I don't mean print(), or head(), or sink() to a file.

This would be useful as one could transfer tables to a separate window without messing up the console.

Comment: `library(htmltools); html_print(pre(paste0(capture.output(print(mtcars)), collapse="\n")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solutions:

view, fix, page, edit

View: Just viewing data frame or matrix
fix: You can edit data (but you can not undo it!)
page: It is like linux less command
edit: it is like fix!
data.entry: it is like fix!

Answer (score 5):

```
vprint <- function(x, ...) {
  require(htmltools)
  html_print(pre(paste0(capture.output(print(x, ...)), collapse="\n")))
}

vcat <- function(...) {
  require(htmltools)
  html_print(pre(paste0(capture.output(cat(...)), collapse="\n")))
}

vprint(mtcars)

vcat(str(mtcars))
```

Comment: How to print text in colour? The `crayon` package does not seem to print anything in colour here

Comment: Is it possible to make the text fit in the window?