# How to print several texts in a window in R in a for loop, so that the text replaces the previous one at each iteration?

Tags: text, shiny, printing, rstudio

I want to print a text in a window with using a loop such as the following one

```r
texts <- c("a", "ab", "abd")
for (t in texts) {
  cat(t, "\n")
  Sys.sleep(1.5) # The real transition time is around 0.05 second
}
```

[image]

- I want the text at each iteration to replace the previous one, I don't want the text to be added vertically
- I want the text to appear in a new window, not in the console of RStudio

Do I have to resort to Shiny? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
vcat <- function(...) {
  require(htmltools)
  html_print(pre(paste0(capture.output(cat(...)), collapse="\n")))
}

texts <- c("a", "ab", "abd")
for (t in texts) {
  vcat(t, "\n")
  Sys.sleep(1.5)
}
```

[image]

Code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34877232/8806649)